# How to use Active Directory connection string membership provider when it is published outside our domain or on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, asp.net-membership

We develop a web application using ASP.NET Webforms and the Active Directory membership provider. It works fine on local server, or on any server has our domain, but when I published it on Azure, it does not work and returns an error

> Unable to establish secure connection with the server

This is my `web.config`:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" 
     connectionString="LDAP://HO-DCRW-V04.test.gov/DC=test,DC=gov"/>

<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" 
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
             connectionUsername="test\mynameaccount" connectionPassword="mypassword"/>
    </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="30" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
<add name="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="adminuser" connectionPassword="adminpassword" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" type="mysystemname.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The error ideally indicates - It is not able to communicate/connect with the **HO-DCRW-V04.test.gov**

Since, the same is working within your local network - I assume the issue is not with the server.

I would start with issuing a LDAP Query outside the **domain network** simultaneously eliminate the Azure of the picture - see if I am provided with the error or able to do it successfully.

Make use of the tools like [LDAP Browser Tool](https://www.ldapadministrator.com/download.htm) where you can check connection string as well as credentials and many more.

Also, I would suggest you (if possible) to make use of the IP Address of the server to which you are issuing the queries. This will enable to directly connecting to server instead of going the DNS resolution.

Comment: thank you for reply , but may be there is one solution is that you must authenticate using azure active directory but i do not know how because after search i reach that you cannot connect directly to our domain from outside :) but still not sure